# Reading lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I have a lambda expression like this `(x => x.FirstName)` and `(x => x.Division.Name)` for the definition `Expression<Func<Employee,object>>`

Now I would like to collect information from this lambda body like the name and type of `FirstName` and the name and type of `Division` then `Name`, how do I do this?

When I browse the value of the expression at debugging I find properties in the expression `Body` that gives this information, but when I try to call these properties at design time I can't find them!

EDIT

The duplicate question answers my question for `(x => x.FirstName)` where `FirstName` is `string`, however while experimenting I found when `(x => x.Age)` where `Age` is `integer` or `bool`, the body `NoteType` becomes `Convert` and the `Body` can't get cast to `MemberExpression`, how should I deal with this situation?

Comment: At design time you won't know the derived types but the debugger figures that out for you.

Comment: Sounds like you might benefit from reading/adapting some of the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/671968/1364007).

Comment: The duplicate has multiple 2009 answers, which are relatively hard, because LINQ framework lacked `ExpressionVisitor`. I added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46852732/335858) that takes advantage of the new addition, which makes the code embarrassingly straightforward.